# After splitting add newline

Tags: python, split

After splitting add newline.
Both queue size = 3;
How to split without '\n' in end

source.txt:

```
234;234
456;567
4567;6789
```

exec:

```
with open('source.txt') as line:
    for source in line:
        result = source.split(";")
        qM.put(result[0])
        qP.put(result[1])
        print(result[0])
        print(result[1])
        print('----')
```

result:

```
234
234

----
456
567

----
4567
6789
----
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this: `using strip()`

```
import Queue

qM = Queue.Queue()
qP = Queue.Queue()

with open('txt') as line:
    for source in line:
        result = source.strip().split(";")
        qM.put(result[0])
        qP.put(result[1])
        print(result[0])
        print(result[1])
        print('----')
```

Output:

```
 234
 234
 ----
 456
 567
 ----
 4567
 6789
 ----
```